# Word for retaining irrelevant parts of old design

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the process of retaining certain aspects of design just because the users are accustomed to seeing it although removing it would not make a major difference?

**Context:** Consider a very old software from the '80s which is being obsoleted with new UI. The new UI is being created to look pretty similar to the old one, like accepting dates in different input fields manually rather than a date picker, just because it would be consistent with the older software. Since the people who decide are apprehensive of new ways of doing things, they want to "keep things consistent" to crazy levels.

**Criteria:** While not limited to software, I am looking for a word that I could use when I want to say something like:

> "I know you crave consistency, but it's high time to stop *[the
> word]*, otherwise there may be serious doubts about our creativity"

Non-software example: I have read that rivets served a purpose on jeans at the time they were invented, but now they are retained only for consistency.

The closest word I have seen so far is *skeuomorphism*. While it has a connotation of taking inspiration from older known objects, I wasn't quite sure if it fits in the above context.

Comment: Do you want a word for the **process** or for that **type of feature**?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent The process of intentional retention of feature of a design which has become superfluous over a period of time.

Comment: When I studied stage design 50 years ago the retention of old costume and architectural features, often as mere decorative elements, was called ***fossilization***.

Comment: Retained (but now irrelevant) elements are ***vestigial***.

Comment: Please read: “[single-word-requests tag wiki](/tags/single-word-requests/info)”. In the question, we need to see exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase – generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.). List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Comment: These can be called **legacy features**.

Comment: You might be interested in the word [anachronism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/anachronism)

Comment: If it is really irrelevant, you may be describing a *packrat* or *compulsive hoarding*. However, the software issue you are describing seems to be *legacy* (as already mentioned) or *backward compatibility*.

Comment: If it existed, your term would be equivalent to *analogue* as opposed to *digital* in clocks and watches: wholly unnecessary except in retrospective contrast… which contrast can’t exist in your context. 

Part of the problem is *craving for* rather than the usual, simpler, *craving* which matters more than you might think.

The *rivet* is a fine example, but not of what you meant. Rivets on jeans do still serve the same purpose as at the time they were invented. Even if that were not true, *consistency* would hardly be a correct explanation for their retention.

Comment: If you are being told it is a requirement, it isn't irrelevant - it's a specification. Build it that way. Computers may have changed, but people haven't. And since the last software I worked with was Fortran 77, I can't help with 80's tech - I was done with it by then, but I don't feel completely irrelevant, and I'd like to be able to use a machine. What's a date picker?

Comment: Oh, and nobody cares about your creativity.  I want stuff that runs for 50 years without major issues and unplanned expenses. Meaning  the issues have been sorted out over time.  Recording dates on records actually precedes the alphabet in human history. So we've got that sorted out now - or at least we had got it sorted until computers came along (Y2K bug, anyone?). Studying history will serve you and your customers more than bemoaning it. Most things we encounter in daily life are done the way they are for very good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In biology, 'vestigal' has a similar meaning. Perhaps it works for your case?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. While I agree that *vestigial* is a reasonable option, your answer would be greatly strengthened by *explaining* why you suggest it, providing illustrative examples and references; there is no fiddle for the English language where a bare answer like this can be tested, after all. I also recommend you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: *Vestigial*, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The [Interaction Design Foundation](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/skeuomorphism#:%7E:text=Skeuomorphism%20is%20a%20term%20most,icon%20used%20for%20discarding%20files.) explains

> **Skeuomorphism** is a term most often used in graphical user interface design to describe interface objects that mimic their real-world counterparts in how they appear and/or how the user can interact with them. A well-known example is the recycle bin icon used for discarding files. Skeuomorphism makes interface objects familiar to users by using concepts they recognize.

Comment: The OP already included this, albeit hesitantly; to make this useful, you should explain why this actually might fit their context.  Add details, please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Nostalgia**, the yearning of things past, which in your example, long ago as obsolete.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nostalgia

Comment: *Nostalgia* is not a *process of retaining certain aspects of design*, and in fact would only apply if those aspects of design were removed rather than retained. Please [edit] your post to clarify, if I have misinterpreted what you are trying to say.